# CallLog not giving the correct NUMBER value (Number dialled)

Tags: android

I'm using `CallLog`, and setting one of my variables to the `CACHED_NAME` of the contact who the user dialled. This works fine, but in the event that the user dials a number which is not in their contacts I would like it to instead set the variable to the `NUMBER` value. For some reason when I do this I get results as single digit integers, such as "1" or "7". Here is my code:

```
Uri allCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    String sortOrder = CallLog.Calls.DATE;
    Cursor c = managedQuery(allCalls, null, null, null, sortOrder);

    while (c.moveToNext()) {

        int callType = Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));
        long date = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.DATE));
        String col1;

        if (callType == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE
                && date > resetDate) {

                col1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.CACHED_NAME));
                // if there is no cached name, get the number
                if (col1 == null) {
                    col1 = String.valueOf(c.getLong(c
                            .getColumnIndex(Calls.NUMBER)));
                }
```

Am I right in saying that the value for `NUMBER` should be the phone number that the user dialled? I know that everything is correct except for the last line where I set `col1` to the number value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `getLong` for the phone number when you should be using `getString`:

```
col1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Calls.CACHED_NAME));
// if there is no cached name, get the number
if (col1 == null) {
    col1 = String.valueOf(c.getString(c
        .getColumnIndex(Calls.NUMBER)));
}
```

Comment: What a rookie mistake! Completely missed that, ended up doing something different anyway, but thanks for the answer.